# How to pass array of numerical values to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-blade

Model

```
 <?php

class Testrundetail extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'testrundetail';

    public static function getAll ()
    {
        $getAll = DB::table('testrundetail')
            ->orderBy('platform', 'asc')
            ->distinct()
            ->lists('platform');

            return $getAll;    
    }
}
```

Controller

```
class PageController extends BaseController {

        public function home ()
        {
            $var = Testrundetail::getAll();

        return View::make('hello')->with('var', '$var');

        }

        public function about ()
        {

        return View::make('about');
        }

    }
```

hello.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>

    <h1> Hello, {{$var}} </h1>

    </body>

</html>
```

The output of the `getAll()` is: `['2520','stack-Ar','2530','2530ya']`
But in output I get `'Hello $var'`

What am I doing wrong? Though, if I do `hello{{$var[0]}}`, I get the output `'Hello 2'`

Comment: What is expected and what you get ?

Comment: if you want to print an array implode it and echo like {{ implode(',',$var) }} this will work.

Comment: `{{ $var }}` = `echo $var` and `$var` is an array I think and in this case it should not work (should rise an error `Array to string conversion`).

Comment: Why don't you try to `var_dump($var)`, and see what's inside your var ???Try this, may be it will helpful..

Comment: Sheikh : the output is like ['2520','2530ya','2530ya','3500'] and so on ..
I am not getting any error ..
what i am getting is hello,$var

Comment: umefarooq.. oohh yes.. it wrks

thanks everyone :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all

```
return View::make('hello')->with('var', '$var');
```

should become

```
return View::make('hello')->with('var', $var);
```

otherwise you will print '$var',

second you will pass an array of objects to the view, so in the view type something like:

```
@foreach($var as $item)
    <li> 
        {{$item->columnName}} 
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using {{$var}}. {{ }} braces are used to echo php variable when we use blade templating. and if you are not using blade templating, then simply go with core php concept.

simply use

```
 var_dump($var);
 or print_r($var);
```

[click here](http://laravel.com/docs/templates)
 to know about blade templating.